# How can I select odd and even elements with CSS?

Tags: html, css

Say I have some divs:

```
<div class="box-1"></div>
<div class="box-2"></div>
<div class="box-3"></div>
<div class="box-4"></div>
```

If these boxes need to be alternate colours I need to create some CSS which basically does the following:

```
.box-(odd-number) {
    color:#000;
}
.box-(even-number) {
    color:#fff;
}
```

Obviously I know the above is not the correct syntax. Could some one point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You can use the `nth-of-type` pseudo-class, combined with the keywords `odd` and `even`:

```css
.box:nth-of-type(odd) {
background-color:#000;
}
    
.box:nth-of-type(even) {
background-color:#fff;
}

.box {
display: inline-block;
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
border: 1px solid #f00;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
```

Answer (score 11):

You can do this using [`nth-child()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) with [`Even and odd rules`](https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/evenodd.en.html).

```css
.box:nth-child(odd) {
    background: blue;
}
.box:nth-child(even) {
    background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
<div class="box">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
<div class="box">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
<div class="box">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
```

Or you can can do this where `:nth-child(2n)` represents the **even** and `:nth-child(2n+1)` represents the **odd**

```css
.box:nth-child(2n) {
    background: red;
}
.box:nth-child(2n+1) {
    background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
<div class="box">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
<div class="box">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
<div class="box">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

To get this working you need a container of which you can adress the odd and even children like this. You set the class to the container and Format it's children accordingly.

By this you only have to set the class once and can exchange it if needed, without having to modify each child separately:

```
<style type="text/css">

.container div:nth-child(odd) {
    color:#F00;
}

.container div:nth-child(even) {
    color:#00F;
}

</style>
<div class="container">
   <div class="box-1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
   <div class="box-2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
   <div class="box-3">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
   <div class="box-4">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for `nth-child(odd)` and `nth-child(even)`, If you don't want to apply `.box` classname.

```
[class^="box-"]:nth-child(odd) {
    color:#000;
}
[class^="box-"]:nth-child(even) {
    color:#fff;
}
```

An example: https://jsfiddle.net/8tkcuuwm/

Answer (score 2):

See this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aqjmvyqb/):

**HTML**

```
<div class="box box-1">Hello World</div>
<div class="box box-2">Hello World</div>
<div class="box box-3">Hello World</div>
<div class="box box-4">Hello World</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.box:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: #336699;
}

.box:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #222;
}
```

**Short explaination:**

We added another class to the boxes, called `box`. This is, so we can refer to every element of this type. (My hint: use ID's for the box-1, box-2 stuff, since they appear to be unique).
Using the `pseudo-class` **nth-child** in combination with **odd** or **even**, will affect every (as you may assume) odd- or even element.

Answer (score 1):

if colours should alternate depending only on the order of the div elements, (no matter the class name) then you could use `div:nth-child(2n)` and `div:nth-child(2n + 1)`

On the contrary if it depends only on the last digit of your class name (no matter if your divs are in the right order) then you could write

```
[class^="box"][class$="2"],
[class^="box"][class$="4"],
[class^="box"][class$="6"],
[class^="box"][class$="8"],
[class^="box"][class$="0"] { ... }

[class^="box"][class$="1"],
[class^="box"][class$="3"],
[class^="box"][class$="5"],
[class^="box"][class$="7"],
[class^="box"][class$="9"] { ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `nth-child` in order to achieve this.

HTML

```
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"><div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
```

CSS

```
.box:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: #000;
}

.box:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #FFF;
}
```