# Sass function for flexbox layout using :nth-of-type(even)

Tags: css, sass

Good afternoon everyone!
I'm trying to create a layout for image section where every odd-numbered image container has an image on the right, text on the left and every :nth-of-type(even) is basically the opposite, image on the left and text on the right.
This is what I have so far, however the nth-of-type(even) selector completely messes up the layout. Without it the code works except the order of image and text does not alternate. Is there a neat Sass way to loop through these items and for each odd one add flex-direction: row-reverse, for each even one flex-direction: row?

This is my HTML for an individual image container, I have 6 in total:

```
<div class="image__container right">

     <div class="image__container-img">
        <img src="" alt='' />
     </div>

     <div class="image__container-text">
       <h3 class="title"></h3>
       <p></p>
       <a href=""></a>
     </div>

    </div>
```

And CSS:

```
.image__container {
    @extend .col;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row-reverse;
    align-items: center;

    &:nth-of-type(even) {
      flex-direction: row;
    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34944698/div-odd-and-even/34944756

Comment: Your code looks correct. Don't know what you mean by "messes up the layout". Want to share a HTML snippet that shows more image__containers? Or you could try to set a background color instead of the the flex-direction just to check whether the selector hits the right elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `> *` to select every child of `.image__container` and with `:nth-of-type(even)` only the even:

```
.image__container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row-reverse;
    align-items: center;

    &>*:nth-of-type(even) {
      flex-direction: row;
    }
}
```